# Overriding `onClick` on a Firefox-Addon ActionButton

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When creating [a plain old `ActionButton`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Adding_a_Button_to_the_Toolbar) in a Firefox Add-on, it seems that one cannot override the `onClick` property after creation. Anyhow, this

```
var handleClick = function() {
  tabs.open('https://www.mozilla.org/');
};

var button = new ActionButton({
  id: 'my-link',
  label: 'label me',
  icon: {
    '16': './icon-16.png',
    '32': './icon-32.png',
    '64': './icon-64.png'
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

button.onClick = function() {
  tabs.open('https://www.github.com/');
};
```

gives a open a tab with `mozilla.org`, not `github.com`.

How to adapt `onClick` after button creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing is probably not to replace the handler but its data:

```
var url = 'https://www.mozilla.org/';
var handleClick = function() {
  tabs.open(url);
};

// ...

url = 'https://www.github.com/';
```

Answer (score 1):

The [API Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action) suggest using [`on`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#on()) which is a common pattern for adding event listeners.

```
button.on('click', handleClick);
```

although this will add *another* click handler, not *replace* the original handler.  Hang onto a reference to the handler (`handleClick` for example) and use [`button.removeListener(handleClick)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#removeListener()) to remove the old one.

Comment: `TypeError: button.prototype is undefined`